# ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView, constraintHeight_percent breaks scrolling

Tags: android, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I have such XML layout with ScrollView and only child ConstraintLayout inside it. Then I have several child views inside this ConstraintLayout usually with wrap content. But I want to have one of this child view of Constrain Layout to fill 80% of screen so I have tried to use **app:layout_constraintHeight_percent** but it breaks Scrolling. It seems like view really has 80% of height but then remaining content happens to occupy just remaining 20%, and it fits screen height, and other views below my Custom View are ignored.

```
<ConstraintLayout>
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendarBackgroundLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- child views with wrap content --> 

        <com.mydomain.CustomView
                android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"

                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.8"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,5:8"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/view_above_this" />

        <!-- additional child views with wrap content --> 
</ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What version of ScrollView are you using?

Comment: If I cmd click on ScrollView there is Android API 28 Platform and bytecode version 52. The odd thing is that If I changed layout_constraintHeight_percent to 0.9 then it start scrolling but now it is much larger than 0.9 percent of screen height like 2x screenHeight

Comment: Interesting... Try emulate what you want using vertical Guidelines...
Also, you didn't post enough of your layout but it looks that you have a ConstraintLayout nested inside of another ConstraintLayout and that nested CL has it's width set to 'match_parent' which isn't recommended.

Comment: Also, there was a known bug when nesting a ConstraintLayout inside of a ScrollView. It has been fixed but I am unsure of which version of ConstraintLayout library you are using. What's the number inside of your build.gradle file?

Comment: I forgot to click cmd+K to format source code. I have ConstraintLayout in ScrollView. The outer ConstraintLayout could be just FrameLayout I think

Comment: build.gradle ConstraintLayout is 1.1.2